# MySQL Procedure Not Recognising Parameter

Tags: mysql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm used to MSSQL, not MySQL so hopefully this is an obvious fix but I've reviewed a lot of questions on here and manuals etc and can't see why I'm getting this error...

I've written a complex procedure which isn't working; I've isolated the issue to how I'm passing in parameters. I've replicated my issue in a small dummy procedure (below):

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE testProcedure(IN startSite CHAR(2), IN endSite CHAR(2))

    SELECT * FROM sys_sites WHERE ssi_uid = startSite;
    SELECT * FROM sys_sites WHERE ssi_uid = endSite;

END
//
DELIMITER;
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:

> CREATE PROCEDURE testProcedure(IN startSite CHAR(2), IN endSite
>   CHAR(2))
>
> SELECT * FROM sys_sites WHERE ssi_uid = startSite;  SELECT * FROM
>   sys_sites WHERE ssi_uid = endSite;     END
>
> > 1054 - Unknown column 'endSite' in 'where clause'
> >     Time: 0s

Please - can anyone advise what obvious thing I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE testProcedure(IN startSite CHAR(2), IN endSite CHAR(2))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM sys_sites WHERE ssi_uid = startSite;
    SELECT * FROM sys_sites WHERE ssi_uid = endSite;

END
//
DELIMITER;
```

u missed begin now try and see.

Comment: Also needs a space between delimiter and the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you - I originally wrote with BEGIN and END as I would for MSSQL and removed both, didn't realise when I put the END back in that I forgot the BEGIN!

It worked without needing the space between DELIMITER and the delimiter.